# Change the scale of x axis in autoplot()

Tags: r, forecasting

There is a lot of similar posts with good replies but none of these is successfull in my case.

The output of forecast is plotted using autoplot():

```
fcast1SA <- forecast(fit1aSA,h=32)
gf <- autoplot(fcast1SA, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Cars") +
        ggtitle("Forecasts until 2050. from ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift")
```

gf is plotted by the default scale on x-axis ranging from 0 to 60 (0 20 40 60).
the idea is to have 0 = 1985, 20 = 2000, 40 = 2020 and 60 = 2050.

I tried with different forms of `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1985, 2050))`... and also with `scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("0", "20", "40", "60"),labels=c("1985", "2000", "2020", "2050"))` but without success.

The most frequent error is:

> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which
> will replace the existing scale.

Please give me some suggestions.

Existing graph is here: